# Saving Django xml in a file?

Tags: python, xml, django, flash

I have a function in a view that renders the xml in the browser, but what I want is to save the xml content to a file, to be used in a Flash gallery.

```
def build_xml_menu(request):    
    rubros = Rubro.objects.all()
    familias = Familia.objects.all()
    context_data = {'rubros': rubros, 'familias': familias}
    return render_to_response('menu.xml', context_data,
        mimetype='application/xml')
```

How can the community help me do this or refer me to a guide that may aid me with this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use [`render to string`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#the-render-to-string-shortcut) instead of `render_to_response` :)